# Sudden pencil problem

Tags: grease-pencil

I just recently started using Blender and today I started an animatic with the regular pencil, with the sensibility and transparency but suddenly (I probably touched something without realizing it) all of the animatic was opaque and the lines were all of the same size. So can I make the drawings back to normal or do I have to entirely redo it? :/ and how can I switch back to the regular pencil pls? (the picture is how it looks like now and of course dumb as I am I forgot to save it before it happened ahah)[image]